# Click button in child component to pass data to parent (via one other child)

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Is it possible to pass data by clicking on the button in nested child component, pass it to anoter child component that is level above and then to parent component?

My components are nested this way:

```
Parent
----Child
---------Child 2 (with the button that should trigger action)
```

So Child 2 look like this:(I added the `addList()` method that should push the variable to the list that is in the parent)

```
<template>
  <li class="movie">
<div class="movie__image">
  <img class="movie__poster" :src="imageURL" :alt="movie.Title"/>
  <button class="movie__more" :href="`https://www.imdb.com/title/${movie.imdbID}`" target="_blank">Add</button>
</div>
  </li>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'movie-list-item',
  props: {
    movie: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addList(event) {
      this.$emit('clicked', this.movie.imdbID)
    }
  }
 </script>
```

Child 1

```
<template>
  <ul class="grid">
  <movie-list-item li v-for="movie in movies" :movie="movie" :key="movie.imdbID" />
</ul>
</template>

<script>
import MovieListItem from './MovieListItem'

export default {
  name: 'movie-list',
  components: {
    MovieListItem
  },
  props: {
    movies: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Parent:(I want to push the item from child 2 component to `picked` list.

```
<template>
   <div>
    <movie-list :movies="movies"></movie-list>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import MovieList from './components/MovieList'

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    MovieList,
  },
  data () {
    return {
      show:false,
      movies: [],
      picked:[]
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using any kind of state management, you'll have to emit two time.

Otherwise, you can use Vuex and have a state management.

Child1

```
<template>
  <ul class="grid">
    <movie-list-item li v-for="movie in movies" :movie="movie" :key="movie.imdbID" @clicked="handleClick(movie.imdbID)" />
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import MovieListItem from './MovieListItem'

export default {
  .....
  methods: {
    handleClick(imdbID) {
      this.$emit("clicked", imdbID);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Parent

```
<template>
   <div>
    <movie-list :movies="movies" @clicked="handleClick($event)"></movie-list>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import MovieList from './components/MovieList'

export default {
 ...
 data () {
    return {
      show:false,
      movies: [],
      picked:[]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick(imdbID) {
      this.picked.push(imdbID);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Shouldnt the @clicked be attached to the button in the child 2 component?

Comment: Becaue actually the child 2 comopnent looks like this: `<li class="movie">
    <div class="movie__image">
      <img class="movie__poster" :src="imageURL" :alt="movie.Title"/>
      <button class="movie__more" :href="`https://www.imdb.com/title/${movie.imdbID}`" target="_blank">Add</button>
    </div></li>`  (see updated code in question), so your solution does not work for me

Comment: No. My method still is correct. On Child 1, you listen to the event called "clicked", which you defined in child 2. The `this.$emit('clicked', this.movie.imdbID)` means that you defined an event called "clicked", and passing the imdbID. So in child 1, I listen to  the "clicked" event, and then I emit it again. My example never touched the child 1